# How to stop BottomSheet sudden collapsing behaviour due to a NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview

The problem I'm facing is that when the scroll of a nestedScrollView finishes, bottom sheet suddenly closes and goes into COLLAPSED state. This does not happen when bottomSheet does not have a nestedScrollView.

This shows a layout with NestedScrollView collapsing suddenly.

[image]

This shows a layout which is a simple LinearLayout which does not have this issue.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: i found this useful https://github.com/trafi/anchor-bottom-sheet-behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Raghunandan. Turns out it wasn't the bottomSheet, but the viewPager which was causing the issue. Turning off swiping in the viewPager does not cause the issue anymore.